# Programmatically access G Suite domain public documents (G Drive documents public to all employees, for example)

Tags: oauth, scope, google-drive-api, google-workspace, drive

**Problem:**

I would like to programmatically access the G Drive documents that are visible to all employees (gDrive documents visible to all G Suite users of a company domain)

**Tried:**

1) Service account with the needed scope - I could not find a proper scope for G Drive Internally Public, the closest is "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly", but it still gives too much permission to the service account, we like it to be limited to "company internally public"

2) Per-user OAuth - it would asks each employee to go through the OAuth permission flow, not desired experience, and asks for more than it needs

**Ask:**

What would be the suggested approach to programmatically access the G Suite domain public G Drive files?

We could try using one dedicated G Suite account's credential, but concerning if it will get throttled/limited when we proxy all company search traffic via this account.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you don't want to use [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts). They seem the obviously solution here, what are you saying it has too much permission? You would the one controlling what the service account will access?
Take a ook at the [`list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list). There are parameters to filter for files inside a domain.

Comment: @Raserhin I believe the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly" would give the service account the metadata read-only ability to access any documents within a domain, I like it to be restricted to the ones that are only public internally, not the ones that shared privately.